# SocketPermission - Client Port?

Tags: java

I've been developing a web application that gets deployed in Apache Tomcat 6, running Java 6 Update 31. There is a requirement to include a module that will simply listen to incoming TCP traffic on port X for future processing. Everything was working great until we went to enable the Java Security Manager (an IA requirement).

Once it was enabled, we started getting AccessControlExceptions, but this was expected, since nothing in our policy file was explicitly allowing this traffic. So, I added the following lines to Tomcat's "catalina.policy" file (where 54321 is the port the app is listening on):

```
grant {
  permission java.net.SocketPermission "*:54321", "accept, resolve";
};
```

However, we were still seeing AccessControlExceptions, such as:

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.net.SocketPermission 192.168.1.50:1527 accept,resolve)
```

Looking at that error line, I noticed that "192.168.1.50" is in fact the IP of the client, so "1527" must be the client-side port for the socket. This is verified by the fact that this port changes each time this is attempted...

So, my question is: why does my web application need to care about the client port? My understanding is that outgoing connections simply use arbitrary/random ports. It seems to me that on my side, with respect to this policy file, I should only need to specify the ports I want to listen to. However, the only way I can get this to work is if I change "54321" to "*" in the above permission line, thereby opening the JVM up to the world.

Am I misunderstanding something about the syntax here? How can I make sure that my application accepts connections from ANY host, from ANY client-side port, on server port 54321?

Thanks,
 Doug

Answer (score 0):

The socket permission *:54321/accept allows you to accept connections from any host using the remote port 54321. That does not make much sense, but a permission like e.g. 192.168.1.50:*/accept would allow you to accept connections from 192.168.1.50 using any port.

If you want to listen for incoming connections on port 54321, you need a permission *:54321/listen (not accept). You can combine these permissions to describe on which local ports your Java process is allowed to listen and from which remote hosts it is allowed to accept connections.

Comment: This would make sense to me, except that on the Javadoc for SocketPermission, the following is found:
'The "listen" action is only meaningful when used with "localhost"'
[(SocketPermission)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/SocketPermission.html)

Comment: And the problem is? Do you want to listen for incoming connections on a remote server?

Comment: So, just to clarify... assuming 192.168.1.50 is the IP of the remote client, I would include two SocketPermission lines: localhost:54321/listen, 192.168.1.50:*/accept ?